# Python urllib2 open POST performance improvement

Tags: python, performance, urllib2

I am relatively new to Python Web programming and need some quick tips/suggestions/techniques to improve the load performance of a REST based API call, using POST. A typical example of a POST call that I need to make(and this is inside a loop that can run over several thousand iterations):

```
r = urllib2.urlopen(request, json.dumps(data))
```

My payload data is in json format and is not heavily nested and doesn't have many multi-values attributes.

What are my options? Are there any Python native libraries which can create a reusable call interface which can keep the connection alive till the entire loop completes?

I cannot use new modules like requests etc due to some environment restrictions.

Thanks for any suggestions possible-
Abhishek

Comment: If you're make POST requests in a loop, wouldn't you want to collect all the data in a list and make just a single call? You can update the API to process batch request. I'm assuming here that you own/manage the API.

Comment: Hi @Oluwafemi Sule I don't have control over the API to change it to process batch requests. The team that developed the API isn't available anymore and hence I would need to contend with a single request at a time in a loop. The program I'm going to create is effectively the new batch API Program:)

Comment: You can try adding `Connection: keep-alive` header before each request. First, you instantiate a Request, set the header. You can then pass the request each time to `urlopen`. Let me know if this works or was a terribly bad idea.

Comment: Thanks "+1" @Oluwafemi Sule this helped improve performance by about a quarter second per POST request. Ironically, when I used requests for the same task the time taken was more( I also had to do a verify=False) than what urllib2 gave me